# Full Page design: How to force a Div to stop expanding at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, overflow

I'm sorry if the title is a bit confusing but I wasn't sure how to describe my problem in a single sentence. So basically I've been struggling since a few days on a Full Page/Screen design.

In my design I've multiple Div that contain some text and one of them is a lot bigger that the height of a normal screen resolution. Moreover I don't want the website to have scrolls on the side of the viewer's browser and I rather have a scroll in the Div that is too big (such as using *overflow: auto;* in this div). However I can't seem to be able to get at the same time the right positioning of the div and the scroll.

[Here is a CodePen of my situation](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IlKtq), I want the red and blue Div to be positioned like that but I would also want the blue div to stop expanding when it reaches the bottom of the page and to have a scroll if it does happen.

The only way I've found to get a scroll would be by using *max-height* or *absolute positioning*. However none of these solutions are viable since the max-height of the blue div is different for every screen resolutions and the height of the red div isn't fixed. Also if I try to use absolute positioning I end up with the blue div standing above the red div since the absolute positioning of the blue div makes it leave "the flow" (and I can't use *margin-top: "height of the red div"*; to solve this problem because the height of the red div isn't fixed).

Hopefully my explanation was clear and somebody will be able to help me. By the way I rather not use JS but if it's necessary I'll use it. Additionally I would welcome a solution that doesn't on old version of IE since none of my viewers are using them.

Thanks, Thomas A

**EDIT:** Just to be clearer I want it to look like [that](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGlom) but with the height of the blue div (*#bottom-inside-container*) being dynamic and not fixed (going from the start of the div to the bottom of the page whatever the size of the page)

Comment: where do you use clear:both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say about your second failed option (using absolute positioning on blue div) that it couldn't be done cause it left the normal flow. Well, I made that blue div be absolute while not leaving the normal flow, by enclosing both red and blue divs in relative parents, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KEdwG

But then, it still fails.. the reason is, what height do you set your now absolute blue div to? You can't give an answer, nor I, but the "overflow:scroll" needs to know at what height to start scrolling. That is the reason why this can't be done solely with CSS.

So if you don't mind adding two lines of jquery to your `document.ready()` , see [**my pen**](http://codepen.io/nbenitez/pen/wrnLg) about solving it that way, you can ignore the `window.resize()` code for your page, as I putted it in the pen so you can drag the iframe vertically and see how the blue div keeps maintaining the expected height.

Also, if you look at css comments of my pen, I change your `left:25px` to be `4%` as it's needed for the relative parents to get it right (besides it's better to use % than px in general).

I paste here the pen jquery code just for convenience:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  max = $(document).height() - $('#bottom-inside-container').offset().top;
  $('#bottom-inside-container').css('max-height',max);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I've been trying for a few days to achieve the same result as yours without using jQuery but I guess it won't be possible. So I'll be using some JS after all (it's not the end of the world :D). I'll try to include your solution to my website right now and if it works I'll mark my topic as solved.

Comment: Ok it works great on my website. By the way I remove _#top-insideparent_ and directly used position:relative; on _#top-inside-container_. Moreover I kept both line of jQuery, otherwise _#bottom-inside-container_ height wouldn't change if the viewer change is browser size while he's on the website. I ended with that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fLKJH which what i wanted. Thanks @Nelson !

Comment: Sorry it says that I need a reputation of 15 to be able to upvote your answer :/.

Comment: Surely $(window).height()? Using document stops the div growing any bigger than it started out, but if it starts out larger than the screen this isn't going to work, surely?

Answer (score 10):

3 years later with the better browsers' support is easy with flexbox property. You could have **added** the following to your CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction:column;
}
#top-inside-container {
    flex-grow:2;
}
#bottom-inside-container {
    flex-grow:1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Setting flex-grow:2 in the top inside container, which is small, is what makes it grow until it shows all it's content. Setting overflows on the bottom inside container will hide (for horizontal scrolling) and set (for vertical scrolling) the scrollbars depending on how much content it has to show.

Here is a code based on your codepen with minimal modifications:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLKENA

PD: I came from Google searching for a similar answer... it could help somebody anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper does not scroll because it has no height (or 100%).
Then, the default browser scrolling is applied, but you can't scroll at your wrapper level.

Scrolling works by simply giving a height to your wrapper - Ex:

```
#wrapper { 
  position:fixed;
  right:550px;
  left:0;
  background:rgb(200,200,200);
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I already thought about this solution but the problem is that I would like to only have a scroll in the blue div (_#bottom-inside-container_) and not the entire wrapper. 

I want it to look like that : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGlom but with the height of the blue div being dynamic and not fixed (going from the start of the div to the bottom of the page whatever the size of the page).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the blue div to position: absolute and then setting both top and bottom values. i.e.

```
html, body{
    width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
#top-inside-container {
    position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100px; background:rgb(75,0,0);
}
#bottom-inside-container {
    position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 100px; bottom: 0; background:rgb(0,75,200); overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here it is working:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qnwFf

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem with your code is that you give a height of 100px to the red div (_#top-inside-container_) but on my website the red div won't have a fixed height so I can't give _#bottom-inside-container_ a fixed number of px as a value for the "_top_" attribute.

Comment: In that case I believe you will need to use javascript to measure the height of the red div, in order to set the top value on the blue one.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I think that the use of some JS in inevitable (cf. Nelson's answer). Anyway thank a lot for your help !